# Problemas con la terminal de Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tengo el siguiente problema en la  terminal de Linux
estoy utilizando Ubuntu y me aparece este error WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800705aa

No me deja escribir ningún comando y se cierra cuando presiono cualquier tecla.

Comment: Creo que es más que relevante indicar que estas usando ubuntu sobre güindous con wsl, cierto?

Comment: Exacto, tienes toda la razón